# Lagging vector adding 1 while resetting to 0 when a condition is met

Tags: r, lag, cumsum

I have a sequence of treatments, one per day (binary), say:

```
trt <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

I want to create a vector, `days_since`, that:

1. Is NA up until the first treatment.
2. Is 0 where `trt` is 1
3. Counts the days since the last treatment

So, the output `days_since` should be:

```
days_since <- c(NA, NA, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2)
```

How would I do this in R? To get `days_since`, I basically need to lag by one element and add 1, but resetting every time the original vector (`trt`) is 1. If this is doable without a for-loop, that would be ideal, but not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
v <- cumsum(trt)
replace(ave(trt,v,FUN = seq_along)-1,v<1,NA)
```

which gives

```
[1] NA NA  0  1  2  3  0  1  2
```

---

**Explanation**

- First, we apply `cumsum` over `trt` to group the treatments

```
> v <- cumsum(trt)
> v
[1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

- Secondly, using `ave` helps to add sequential indices within each group

```
> ave(trt,v,FUN = seq_along)-1
[1] 0 1 0 1 2 3 0 1 2
```

- Finally, since the value is `NA` before the first treatment, it means all the value before `v == 1` appears should be replaced by `NA`. Thus we use `replace`, and the index logic follows `v < 1`

```
> replace(ave(trt,v,FUN = seq_along)-1,v<1,NA)
[1] NA NA  0  1  2  3  0  1  2
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you explain what's happening in the second line here? Specifically, `ave(trt,v,FUN = seq_along)`?

Answer (score 4):

We can also use

```
(NA^!cummax(trt)) * sequence(table(cumsum(trt)))-1
#[1] NA NA  0  1  2  3  0  1  2
```

---

Or with `rowid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
(NA^!cummax(trt)) *rowid(cumsum(trt))-1
#[1] NA NA  0  1  2  3  0  1  2
```

Comment: Fantastic solution! Learned `sequence` from you :)